# Are the package deliveries from France (Paris) to Thailand (Bangkok) delayed/blocked due to COVID-19?

Tags: france, thailand, covid-19, postal-system

I need to get some package from my birth country, France, and I am currently located in Thailand. Are the package deliveries from France (Paris) to Thailand (Bangkok) delayed/blocked due to COVID-19? If that matters, it is a small box (~40cm x 30 cm x 20) weighting ~3 kg.

Comment: Did you ask the carrier(s) you might use if their service is currently delayed?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Not yet, but I have a low confidence in the customer service of French carriers, so I'm mostly interested in empirical results from customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to users sharing their experiences on https://redd.it/hw0auu ([mirror](http://archive.is/X67oZ)), package deliveries from France (Paris) to Thailand (Bangkok) are not blocked due to COVID-19, but they're quite often delayed (typically ~1 week to ~1 month).